# AmoCRM webhook - Golang бинд json в структуру

Tags: golang, echo

Я пишу интеграционный webhook сервис, использую язык golang (фреймворк Echo). При обработке запроса от amoCRM возникает проблема: Вместо того что бы отсылать json в теле запроса они отсылают его в параметрах и из за этого у меня не получается забиндить его в структуру.

Вот такой запрос приходит от amoCRM:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой хендлер, в котором я хочу просто получить строку json из тела:

```
func changedLeadStatus(c echo.Context) error {
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request().Body)
    bodyString := string(bodyBytes)

    log.Println(bodyString)
    return c.NoContent(http.StatusOK)
}
```

Но вместо json я получаю вот это:

```
leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=10939363&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bstatus_id%5D=21721936&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bold_status_id%5D=21721930&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bprice%5D=&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bresponsible_user_id%5D=2778463&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Blast_modified%5D=1538396718&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bmodified_user_id%5D=2778463&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcreated_user_id%5D=2778463&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bdate_create%5D=1538385281&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bpipeline_id%5D=1357129&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=531499&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=test_event&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Baccount_id%5D=21721924&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=629659&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=roistat&leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=4&account%5Bsubdomain%5D=intexcons
```

И это не разу не json, помогите пожалуйста сбиндить это дело.

Comment: У вас в запросе `Content-Type` не `application/json`. Вот вам echo и превращает ответ в форму. Ещё одна причина любить "умные" фреймворки.

Comment: Я пробовал и обычными средствами без Echo, результат такой же в Body лежит такая же строка как и в Echo

Comment: Это может значить, что именно такие данные шлются вам. Попробуйте определить для своих структур тэг `form:"foo"`, как описано [здесь](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/request) и вызвать на неё `c.Bind`.

Comment: Я так и делаю, тэги стоят

Comment: Добавьте структуры в вопрос. Может, там дело.

Answer (score 0):

5 лет? Серьёзно? Ну ладно.

По всей видимости их бэк написан на PHP, а там для декодирования исользуют функцию parse_str со своим не стандартизированным форматом. Сам с этой проблемой столкнуля и нашёл её реализацию в Golang:

```
func parseStr(encodedString string, result map[string]any) error {
// build nested map.
var build func(map[string]any, []string, any) error

build = func(result map[string]any, keys []string, value any) error {
    length := len(keys)
    // trim ',"
    key := strings.Trim(keys[0], "'\"")
    if length == 1 {
        result[key] = value
        return nil
    }

    // The end is slice. like f[], f[a][]
    if keys[1] == "" && length == 2 {
        // todo nested slice
        if key == "" {
            return nil
        }
        val, ok := result[key]
        if !ok {
            result[key] = []any{value}
            return nil
        }
        children, ok := val.([]any)
        if !ok {
            return fmt.Errorf("expected type '[]any' for key '%s', but got '%T'", key, val)
        }
        result[key] = append(children, value)
        return nil
    }

    // The end is slice + map. like f[][a]
    if keys[1] == "" && length > 2 && keys[2] != "" {
        val, ok := result[key]
        if !ok {
            result[key] = []any{}
            val = result[key]
        }
        children, ok := val.([]any)
        if !ok {
            return fmt.Errorf("expected type '[]any' for key '%s', but got '%T'", key, val)
        }
        if l := len(children); l > 0 {
            if child, ok := children[l-1].(map[string]any); ok {
                if _, ok := child[keys[2]]; !ok {
                    _ = build(child, keys[2:], value)
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
        child := map[string]any{}
        _ = build(child, keys[2:], value)
        result[key] = append(children, child)

        return nil
    }

    // map. like f[a], f[a][b]
    val, ok := result[key]
    if !ok {
        result[key] = map[string]any{}
        val = result[key]
    }
    children, ok := val.(map[string]any)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("expected type 'map[string]any' for key '%s', but got '%T'", key, val)
    }

    return build(children, keys[1:], value)
}

// split encodedString.
parts := strings.Split(encodedString, "&")
for _, part := range parts {
    pos := strings.Index(part, "=")
    if pos <= 0 {
        continue
    }
    key, err := url.QueryUnescape(part[:pos])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for key[0] == ' ' {
        key = key[1:]
    }
    if key == "" || key[0] == '[' {
        continue
    }
    value, err := url.QueryUnescape(part[pos+1:])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // split into multiple keys
    var keys []string
    left := 0
    for i, k := range key {
        if k == '[' && left == 0 {
            left = i
        } else if k == ']' {
            if left > 0 {
                if len(keys) == 0 {
                    keys = append(keys, key[:left])
                }
                keys = append(keys, key[left+1:i])
                left = 0
                if i+1 < len(key) && key[i+1] != '[' {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if len(keys) == 0 {
        keys = append(keys, key)
    }
    // first key
    first := ""
    for i, chr := range keys[0] {
        if chr == ' ' || chr == '.' || chr == '[' {
            first += "_"
        } else {
            first += string(chr)
        }
        if chr == '[' {
            first += keys[0][i+1:]
            break
        }
    }
    keys[0] = first

    // build nested map
    if err := build(result, keys, value); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}

return nil
}
```